# Error in Fragment while implementing custom Calendar

Tags: android, calendar, fragment

I am trying to implement a calendar in a fragment.

Java File

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment {

public FindPeopleFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    HashSet<Date> events = new HashSet<>();
    events.add(new Date());
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    CalendarView cv = ((CalendarView)getView().findViewById(R.id.calendar_view));
    cv.updateCalendar(events);

    // assign event handler
    cv.setEventHandler(new CalendarView.EventHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDayLongPress(Date date)
        {
            // show returned day
            DateFormat df = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance();
            Toast.makeText(FindPeopleFragment.this.getActivity(), df.format(date), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

This is the error I am getting:

Error Log

```
/Users/stiffmaster/AndroidStudioProjects/Main/app/src/main/java/tiphinbox    /main/FindPeopleFragment.java
Error:(48, 5) error: missing return statement
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

**Question**

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: Have you read the error message? Have you considered doing exactly what it tells you to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to understand what the error is trying to say. It says that return statement is missing. So you should check all the functions that are expected to return values in their method signature but are not returning.

Quick check shows that you are not returning `View` in your `onCreateView` method.

Good luck!